# Image Detection and Verification of State Based on Area

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am currently working on a project where I must differentiate a normal cell from a diseased cell. The specific abnormality I am looking at states that the cell nucleus should have a certain area and mostly circular. I am currently using scipy, numpy and PIL to determine the presence of nuclei (see below images)...but I am unsure how to determine the area since the nucleus will not always be a perfect circle. Any suggestions?

[Original Image before processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbZpR.jpg)

[image: Original Image before processing]

[Only nuclei are shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdLYL.png)

[image: Only nuclei are shown (Mapped Image)]

Comment: Since you already seem to have a nice segmentation (you're almost there!)  - I would just use a threshold for each color (0/1) - so you get a black picture with just your one particle, then add up the values, so you have the area (with a factor/in pixels). If you need "real" areas, you would need your camera calibration/a reference object.

You will probably want to research shape factors /compactness measure. If you have multiple particles of the same color, this does not work. Then, look into seeding.

Comment: You might also look at the nice tutorial
[pythonvision.org](http://pythonvision.org/basic-tutorial)
"take this image and count the number of nuclei",
and also at [cellprofiler](http://www.cellprofiler.org)
"free open-source software designed to enable biologists ... to 
quantitatively measure phenotypes from thousands of images
automatically".
I haven't used either of these myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the scale of your image, then just count the number of pixels that fall inside the cell region. Then that number divided by total number of pixels in the image gives you the fraction of the image area taken up by the cell. If you know your image resolution, then you should know the area of that rectangular image domain. Multiply the two to get cell area.

Some sources of inaccuracy will be (a) if there is poor segmentation (b) if the cells are ever elongated (poor isoperimetric quotient) and the rounding of including/excluding cell boundary pixels then matters, or (c) if the cell is ever in shadow / not observed in the correct plane to yield its cross-sectional area. But hopefully your experiment includes enough data that you can discard these.

Answer (score 0):

By count each color pixels you get the area, if you already label your data as following:

```
data = np.array([[0,0,1,1,1],
                 [2,2,1,1,1],
                 [2,3,3,3,3],
                 [2,4,4,3,3]])
```

than you can use numpy.bincount() to count each label:

```
print numpy.bincount(data.ravel())
```

the output is :

```
array([2, 6, 4, 6, 2])
```

which means there are two 0, six 1, four 2, six 3, and two 4.